# ckeditor - site won't pick-up ckeditor.js

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Trying to include CKEditor in my project but I keep getting a 404 (Not Found) error. The CKEditor I'm using is a freshly downloaded standard package version 4.4.2. Does anyone know why my site is not able to pick-up CKEditor? I'm not even trying to replace a textarea id with a CKEditor instance yet. I created a test directory with a test javascript file in the same position and those get picked-up fine. Is it because my project files are in php?

My directory listing looks like this:

```
-westpoint (root)
    -ckeditor (contains all ckeditor files)
        -ckeditor.js
    -ck (test folder)
        -ck.js (test js file)
```

Script elements in my head:

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/ck/ck.js"></script>
```

Error in console:

```
GET http://www.qds2013.ca/ckeditor/ckeditor.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: 404 means the resource is not found. Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Is the php file in the root?

Comment: @JTG - the php file referencing ckeditor.js is not in the root. It is in a separate directory.

Comment: I'm just not sure if it's a path issue. When I point my src at ../ckeditor/ckeditor.js I get the same error. That's why I setup a test folder with a JS file in it. No errors picking-up the test file.

Comment: maybe a missing permission on the ckeditor folder?